# ESP8266 - callback with password/mac on wifi client connect

Tags: wifi, esp8266

Background information:

I have a couple hundred autonomous (solar cell + battery) station-mode wifis (not necessarily ESPs) scattered allover the course of a river, monitoring the upstream/downstream water quality, before/along/after peasant houses, city water treatment plants etc. Sensor data is captured and stored every couple of minutes and uploaded to a water drone sailing by weekly. The drone has an ESP8266 acting as AP and providing the required uploading infrastructure.

The problem is:

I will have to grab the drone and take it upstream 3 times, as there are sensors from many batches, each connecting to the same wifi ssid but with a different password...

My question is:

Is it possible to have a callback in the esp with the currently used password for authenticating, BEFORE allowing/refusing client connection?

I hope I made myself clear, yet if there are any questions please ask.

Thank you all for your help and expertise!

Comment: This sounds like one heck of a project, way cool! Do you have a more detailed description somewhere?

Comment: Is the software NodeMCU or Arduino based?

Comment: So, your intention would be to essentially allow _one of three_ passwords?

Comment: Cool idea to have drone over the river! I just wondered, why you got different pass for them, do not they have specific ids or types info to sent to the ap and store?

Comment: @MarcelStör - I am sorry, I cannot provide more details without written consent from all the project owners. Mainly it monitors diluted oxygen level, various chemical levels, water/air temperature, relative humidity above 30cm, sun shine etc.

Comment: @MarcelStör - The software is neither Arduino-based nor NodeMCU-based.

There would be 3 passwords, indeed.

Comment: @cagdas - The devices were created in 3 different batches, depending on what had to be monitored. The different wifi password comes from the different batches, since the development office wifi password leaked too many times. Unfortunately deployed sensors are rosin-sealed, cannot be upgraded (except for battery/solar cell/support replacement). No new sensors could be added neither...

The sensors do collect different information and differ in various amounts. Each sensor has indeed an unique identification.

Comment: Hi @ro0ter, i gave a look at open sdk of espressif but there is no callback assignation to user api before connection event. But i just think that if wrong password callback was suitable for your purpose?

Comment: Hi @cagdas, I know about the esp sdk, we am using rtos. Afaik the wrong password callback is on the client (station) side, isn`t it? We are looking for any possibility to see on the access point side if there is any client (station) trying to connect but being unable to due to bad (different) password. Indeed, a callback with the mac+password would encourage password phishing, but there are many bored people trying to connect to anything that moves hoping on guessing the passwords and that may induce many false situations, if the "wrong password" callback would be on AP side...

Comment: AFAIK there's no such a callback but maybe there's a workaround? Could you just switch the password for a while in order to make devices from different batches able to connect?

Comment: @Defozo We tried doing that but given the low wifi scanning rate (power conservation), it takes a while for every device to detect access points. There are >40% systems unable to report all the data and we cannot control them (have the missing systems report the data in the next run). The best approach is 3 drone runs per week, each with a different pwd... So far the drone is only a huge ball of fiberglass (having painted company + contact details) with a thick styrofoam wall and a temporary water-sealed core where all the electronics go. No complex navigation systems to hold position.

Comment: Do you know the MAC addresses of the clients ?

Comment: @cagdas Yes, the physical addresses of all sensors are well known and they are unique so far. After connecting, each sensor also reports its data with a longer, also unique sensor ID. Is there some trick that can be done with the access point's wifi in promiscuous mode with respect to the station's physical addresses not requiring upgrading (replacement actually, no upgrades are possible) of the stations?

Comment: I wish it could be. There was a wifi sniffer example that was running in promiscuous mode in the sdk example. I cant check it now, having a day off today. Maybe you can go for that example.